# Testing window click and contextmenu events in Angular service with Karma

Tags: angular, karma-runner, addeventlistener

I am working on my library [Contexr](https://github.com/kayvanbree/contexr) and I need to test the window's click and contextmenu events. I want to spy on one of my services and check if some methods are called using a spyOn. I tried several ways using fakeAsync, tick and fixture.detectChanges, but my methods are never called. I know that my events are added, because the method that adds the event listeners is being called. My initialize method looks like this:

```
public initialize() {
  window.addEventListener('click', (event: MouseEvent) => {
    this.close();
  });
  window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event: MouseEvent) => {
    this.contexr.addCurrentContext('all', null);
    this.open(event, {
      context: this.contexr.getCurrentContext(),
      top: event.clientY,
      left: event.clientX
    });
  });
}
```

The spec file looks like this:

```
describe('ContextMenuService', () => {
  let contextMenuService: ContextMenuService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ContextDirectiveTestComponent>;
  let element: DebugElement;
  let contexr: ContexrMockService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    contexr = new ContexrMockService();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ContextDirectiveTestComponent ],
      providers: [
        ContextMenuService,
        { provide: Overlay, useClass: OverlayMock },
        { provide: ContexrService, useValue: contexr }
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContextDirectiveTestComponent);
    contexr = TestBed.get(ContexrService);
    element = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div'));
    contextMenuService = TestBed.get(ContextMenuService);
    contextMenuService.initialize();
  });

  it('should react to window clicks', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(contexr, 'addCurrentContext').and.callThrough();
    element.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    tick(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(contexr.addCurrentContext).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

So, once again I'm asking smarter people on the internet. What is wrong with this test? The click handlers work in the actual application, but I really want to get my code coverage up to ~100% before I will even think of releasing 2.0.0.

Comment: This is not typically the Angular way of binding events. Check out [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/event-binding-mechanism-in-angular-b38f0e46d2ed)

Comment: The problem for that is that I want to bind my events within a server, because no components of my library will be used by any application. The events also need to be handled everywhere on the page, not just on a component. I'll read the article tomorrow, thanks!